# How to make 2 divs that are inside one "top panel" but in different cornes not to overlap one another when window size is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So let us look at google: it looks like:

[image]

But when we resize page it starts to overlap...:

[image]

I wonder how to make it so that when page is minified right div would start to behaive like left ones. I wonder how to create such "top panel" with jQuery?

Comment: You probably wouldn't use jQuery at all! It's simply HTMl + CSS. jQuery isn't some sort of magic wand.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825542/how-i-can-overlap-a-div-on-to-other-div

Answer (score 0):

Tough to tell you exactly what to do since you provided no code, but you want to set a min-width for your menu bar so it's wide enough to accommodate everything.

```
<div id="menuWrapper">
    <div class="left">Left Content</div>
    <div class="right">Right Content</div>
</div>

#menuWrapper{
    min-width:750px;
}
```